# Oracle 11g: Migrated users have ACL set but can't hit utl_http: ORA-24247/29273: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-migration, ora-24247

Situation:

- Oracle 10g database migrated to 11g - users migrated
- Migrated users who call `utl_http.request(...)` fail with error:
  `ORA-29273: HTTP request failed`
  `ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1722`
  `ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)`
  `ORA-06512: at line 8`
- We've created an ACL and added the users/host permissions (connect and resolve), and the users have execute permission to `utl_http`
- Newly created users have no problems with the call once their ACL and execute permissions have been set
- At least one migrated user, dba_monitor, is able to make the call (though that user has other, elevated permissions)

The only difference we've found between the accounts is in dba_user.password_versions... the new ones say `10g 11g`, while the migrated ones say `10g`.

We've tried changing the password for the accounts that can't make the call... this changed the password_versions to `10g 11g`, but still no dice

Dropped and re-added the ACL permissions and grants a number of times, no success.

Does anyone know of known issues with migrating existing Oracle accounts, or have any thoughts on where we can look for more clues?

Thanks!

**Update:**

We went to another 11g instance and created a new user with the same name, CSS_WEB, and set permissions in the ACL.  That user was also unable to connect.  We created a new user, CSS_WEB1, and that user was **ABLE** to connect.

This has gotten really, really strange... at this point I'm not expecting answers, just ideas of where we can look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved this as an OID-related problem.

Somehow, there were OID entries for these accounts, even though they were db local.  When we removed the OID data for them, everything worked.

Comment: Is there some reason people go through comments and answers and delete the part where I say "thank you"?  Signatures and taglines are not allowed by the FAQ, but saying thank you is neither; it's just courtesy.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying a guess here:
Is it possible that the one user which is working is always the last one ?
Because if you assigned the same host to multiple ACLs then only the last one will take effect

Comment: No, the last one will work or not work, depending on the account : (